# Does Spring Cloud LoadBalancer have a timeout like Netflix Ribbon?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

I am trying to make the switch to LoadBalancer. When using Ribbon, I could set these properties to override the default 1000 ms timeouts:

ribbon.ReadTimeout=5000
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=5000

I don't see anything similar in the LoadBalancer documentation.

Does it have timeouts? If so, are they fixed and non-configurable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That timeout was for the ribbon HTTP client. Spring Cloud Loadbalancer does not have a built-in HTTP client so it does not have a timeout.

Comment: thank you. That is an improvement I think because there was always a lot of confusing (to me, anyway) interplay between the various timeouts in the stack.